# Как правильно делать замеры в psd макете?

Tags: html, вёрстка, psd

Никак не могу понять, как нужно замерять размер всей страницы, шрифтов и отдельных блоков в макете `psd`

Например скачал макет замеряю ширину всей страницы, фотошоп показывает размер `1920px` ага значит `max-width:1920` далее шрифты 40 пикслей в навигации, `180px` отступы слева в списке `ul>li =>` верстаю, но то что получается у меня в корне отличается от макета, монструозностью, смотрю пример как свёрстан этот макет, и там ширина страницы `960px`, а все шрифты в половину меньше чем замеряет фотошоп.

Как быть, или не стоит переносить замеры с фотошопа в вёрстку и делать всё приблизително?

Comment: Разные DPI тут случайно не замешаны?

Comment: Если бы я знал, как это можно проверить?

Comment: Действительно похоже на DPI. Если не ошибаюсь обычно макеты рисуют с DPI == 72. Полистайте в гугле, как просмотреть DPI в Photoshop.

Comment: Попробуйте бесплатную софтинку: **Avocode**, зарегистрируйтесь и получите триал, а дальше после окончания подписки повторить действия. Получите хорошего помощника для вёрстки. Насчёт вашей проблемы, несколько вариантов на самом деле, от банального **viewport** в мета в заголовке html документа, до разрешения вашего экрана

Answer (score -1):

Не надо задавать max-width -это неправильно, потому что на больших экранах твоя вeрстка просто нe будет отображаться как надо.

HTML теги, которые предназначены для использовании внутри текста (h1, ... h6, p, span ...) у них есть line-height(default). Первоначально надо задать ее. Поэтому у тебя и не совпадают psd и вeрстка. Провер подключен ли у тебя Font-Family ... Потом oстальное.

Comment: а что насчёт размеров макета?

Comment: Desktop => min-width: 1200px; Tablet-landscape(1024*768) => min-width: 1200px; Tablet-portrait(720*1280, 768*1024) => min-width: 900px; Mobile(320*534, 320*568, 360*640, 375*667) => max-width: 600px

Comment: Или                                                                                                               
Mobile => max-width: 767px; Tablet => min-width768px and max-width: 1024px; Desctop => min-width: 1024px;